# Scrolling issues having a ViewPager as the header in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to stick a ViewPager (horizontal scroll) in a tableview (vertical scroll). It appears that it works unless you do any kind of vertical scroll in the ViewPager which happens normally when trying to swipe. Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this (the trick is to disallow vertical scrolls in the parent as soon as a horizontal scroll is detected):

```
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(
                        true);
            }
        }
    });
```